# Gatling - Run simulations sequentially

Tags: gatling

I would like to run the gatling simulations in a particular order.I am using the sbt extension but unable to figure out how to specify the order of evaluating the simulations.

Comment: You can always do sbt runs sequentially. Or combine scenarios into a sequence within one simulation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can trigger your simulations one by one of this way:

```
sbt gatling:testOnly full.name.Simulation1
sbt gatling:testOnly full.name.Simulation2
sbt gatling:testOnly full.name.Simulation3
```